# Calling jQuery functions on inputs in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a couple of jQuery functions that validate an input field according to a regex. When I have a form embedded on a page, they work fine. However, when I try to use them inside of a Bootstrap Modal they do not work.

Any ideas?

```
<input class="form-control input-lg validate-email" id="email" name="email" minlength="2" type="text"  placeholder="Email">

 $('.validate-email').on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this).val();
    var regex = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    var is_email = regex.test(input);
    if(is_email){
        $(this).removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    } else{
        $(this).removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
```

});

Once again, this code works when the form is on a page, but not when the form is in a Bootstrap Modal.

One more detail, the `valid` and `invalid` are CSS classes that change the background-color of the field to change. If I skip the jQuery and just hardcode an invalid class in the `<input>` it shows the invalid class. So I know it is the jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

function IsEmail(email) {

var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

return regex.test(email);
}

Comment: I don't think that is what I am looking for.